# Why is this object unaccesible?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to scroll the parent from within an iframe (cross-origin). I found the [*iframe resizer*](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) (by David j. Bradshaw) which should be able to accomplish this (i'm using the resizer because i also needed the iframe to resize based on it's content)

I could use [*postMessage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) but since i'm already using the iframe resizer, which has the options to accomplish my goal, it'd be nice to make full use of it.

By using this on the parent:

```
iFrameResize({
    enablePublicMethods     : true
});
```

I should be able to call `window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0)` in the iframe. However, for some reason i can't access `window.parentIFrame`.

When i log `window` in the console i **do** see the `parentIFrame` object, however when i log `window.parentIFrame`, it returns `undefined`.

**Why can't i access the `window.parentIFrame` object**?

This is my current testing situation (copied from the [*example*](http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/), libraries can be found [*here*](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/master/js):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>iFrame message passing test</title> 
        <meta name="description" content="iFrame message passing test"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //MDN PolyFil for IE8 (This is not needed if you use the jQuery version)
            if (!Array.prototype.forEach){
                Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisArg */){
                "use strict";
                if (this === void 0 || this === null || typeof fun !== "function") throw new TypeError();

                var
                t = Object(this),
                len = t.length >>> 0,
                thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (i in t)
                    fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h2>Automagically resizing iFrame</h2>
        <p>Resize window or click one of the links in the iFrame to watch it resize.</p>
        <div style="margin:20px;">
            <iframe src="frame.content.html" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
        <p id="callback">
        </p>
        <div style="margin: 8px 0;font-size:13px;">
            For details on how this works, see
            <a href="http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/">http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/</a>.
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">

            iFrameResize({
                enablePublicMethods     : true
            });


        </script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

**frame.content.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>iFrame message passing test</title> 
        <meta name="description" content="iFrame message passing test">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            *, *:before, *:after {box-model: border-box;}
            a { float:right; margin-left:10px;}
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <b>iFrame</b> 
        <a href='#' onclick="$('p:eq(0)').toggle();return false;">Toggle content</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href='#' onclick="if ('parentIFrame' in window) window.parentIFrame.size(250);return false;">Size(250)</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a id="nested" href="frame.nested.html">Nested</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="frame.hover.html">:Hover</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="frame.absolute.html">Absolute Position</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href='#' onclick="if ('parentIFrame' in window) window.parentIFrame.sendMessage('Hello from the iFrame');return false;">Send Message</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href='#' onclick="if ('parentIFrame' in window) window.parentIFrame.close();return false;">Close</a>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
            But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
        </p>
        <p>
            On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.
        </p>

        <script>

            var level = document.location.search.replace(/\?/,'') || 0;

            $('#nested').attr('href','frame.nested.html?'+(++level));
            console.log(window); // Does show parentIFrame in the list of properties/objects
            console.log(window.parentIFrame); // Returns undefined
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try consle logging `window.parent` and see what you get.

Comment: `window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0)` works fine for me in `Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 m`. I tried in console after activating the iframe as context. What browser are you using? I frame implementations and security might differ along browsers.

Comment: Logging `window.parent` returns the Window object for the parent, as expected. @sabithpocker I'm getting the same results for both Firefox and Chrome (same version as yours). What do you mean with activating the iframe as context?

Comment: @RobinvdA There is a drop down at top of developer console to change window context from parent window `<top frame>` to the iframe you are debugging. Comes in handy when debugging iframes by setting context to that iframe.

Comment: @sabithpocker Oh ok, thnx. Could it be a host problem? Because the example seems to be working fine: [*link*](http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I don't know why but the reason `window.parentIFrame` is undefined is because it isn't available immediately after the page is loaded.

So this (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

won't work. But binding it to a click or something:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
});
```

does work.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the parentIframe is not available directly after document.ready. You may wait one second or more. So you need to put it in a setInterval like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const waitInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.parentIFrame) {
            parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
            clearInterval(waitInterval);
        }
    }, 100);
 })
```